# differentiate current wrt time.

Tags: derivatives

I have an equation which looks like so:

```
i = I(1-exp(-t/tau))
```

and I would like to work out di/dt. I was wondering if someone could show me how to make a start with this problem. From what I see, I write the above as follows:

```
i=I-I*exp(-t/tau)
```

the first part (I) works out to zero, and for the second part (I*exp(-t/tau)), I use product rule. Does this make sense at all?

so, my results look like:

```
0 - I*[(-1/tau)*exp(-t/tau)] + exp(-t/tau)*0
```

which leads to:

```
di/dt = I/tau (exp(-t/tau)
```

Does this look right? I tried inpouting in wolfram alpha, but I am not able to input the `right command` for this problem.

Comment: Is $I$ a constant?

Comment: yes, I is a constant

Comment: Then your answer is correct.

Comment: Oh thanks :) I am not really stupid then! please put this as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct. I'll provide a solution just to outline the steps involved to clear up any confusion. Applying the product rule, using $\frac{d}{dt} \exp(f(t)) = f'(t) \exp(f(t))$ and noting for any constant $c$

$$\frac{d}{dt} c = 0$$

we find

\begin{align}
\frac{di}{dt} &= \frac{d}{dt} I - \underbrace{\frac{d}{dt} \bigg( I \exp \bigg(\frac{-t}{\tau} \bigg) \bigg)}_{\text{product rule}} \\
&= \frac{d}{dt} I - \bigg( \exp \bigg(\frac{-t}{\tau} \bigg) \frac{d}{dt} I + I \underbrace{\frac{d}{dt} \exp \bigg(\frac{-t}{\tau} \bigg)}_{\text{differentiation of exp}} \bigg) \\
&= 0 - \bigg( \exp \bigg(\frac{-t}{\tau} \bigg) \cdot 0 + I \cdot \frac{-1}{\tau} \exp \bigg(\frac{-t}{\tau} \bigg) \bigg) \\
&= \frac{I}{\tau} \exp \bigg(\frac{-t}{\tau} \bigg)
\end{align}

Comment: Thats awesome.. thank you..